# How do the air conditioning packs work for the CRJ 700/900?

Tags: aircraft-systems, cabin-pressure, bombardier-crj

Please provide details on how the packs on the [CRJ 700/900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_CRJ700_series) work. How does the system use air from the packs to make cold air for the aircraft?

Comment: I am pretty sure it works in general like all other A/C systems.